# Colab TPU, xmp.spawn with nproc=8, RuntimeError: Cannot replicate if number of devices (1) is different from 8

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, torch, tpu

I am trying to train the Pix2Struct model from transformers on google colab TPU and shard it across TPU cores as it does not fit into memory of individual TPU cores, but when I do `xmp.spawn()` with `nproc=8`, I get `RuntimeError: Cannot replicate if number of devices (1) is different from 8`. The training works with `nproc=1` but I get out of memory error after a few batches. What could be the issue? Are there any other ways I can optimize the training? My reproducible code is as follows:

```
import torch
import os, json
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from pathlib import Path
import requests
from transformers import AutoProcessor, Pix2StructForConditionalGeneration
from accelerate import Accelerator
import torch_xla
import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm
import torch_xla.distributed.xla_multiprocessing as xmp
import torch_xla.distributed.parallel_loader as pl
from torch_xla.distributed.fsdp import XlaFullyShardedDataParallel as FSDP, checkpoint_module

DEVICE = xm.xla_device()
def train(rank, flags):
    xm.master_print(f"Training function started on rank {rank}")
    processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained("google/pix2struct-textcaps-base")
    model = Pix2StructForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/pix2struct-textcaps-base")
    model.to(DEVICE)
    model = torch_xla.distributed.fsdp.XlaFullyShardedDataParallel(model)
    optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(list(model.parameters()))

    # Load data and distribute across cores
    text_data = ["123456789"]*8
    images = [Image.fromarray(np.ones((2048, 2048, 3), dtype=np.uint8))]*8

    sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(text_data, num_replicas=xm.xrt_world_size(), rank=xm.get_ordinal())
    text_data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(list(enumerate(text_data)), batch_size=1, sampler=sampler)
    mp_device_loader = pl.MpDeviceLoader(text_data_loader, DEVICE)
    
    for epoch in range(flags.epochs):
        for batch in mp_device_loader:
            xm.master_print(batch)
            text = batch[1]  # Assuming your DataLoader provides batches as lists
            image_idx = batch[0]  # Index of the corresponding image
            image = images[image_idx]

            xm.master_print(f"Processing data on rank {rank} with image size {image.size}")
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            inputs = processor(images=image, return_tensors="pt", max_patches=256, truncation=False)
            labels = processor(text=text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

            for k, v in inputs.items():
                inputs[k] = v.to(DEVICE)
                xm.master_print(f"{k}, {v.shape}")
            labels = labels.to(DEVICE)
            xm.master_print(f"{labels.shape}")

            # Forward pass
            outputs = model(**inputs, labels=labels)

            loss = outputs.loss
            xm.master_print(f"{loss.detach():.5f}")
            loss.backward()
            xm.optimizer_step(optimizer, barrier=True)

class Flags():
    def __init__(self, num_cores=8, epochs=1):
        self.num_cores = num_cores
        self.epochs = epochs

flags = Flags()
xmp.spawn(train, args=(flags,), nprocs=1, start_method='fork')
```

The libraries:

```
!pip3 install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 torch==2.0.0 torchvision==0.15.1 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/colab/torch_xla-2.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
!pip3 install dgl transformers datasets pdf2image accelerate
```